# Response 400 on Microsoft Graph - Create calendar event: Property emailAddress in payload has a value that does not match schema

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I'm creating a new calendar event through [Microsoft Graph](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=cs). I'm trying to insert organizer information on a Graph Calendar Event

```
if organizer.get('email'):
    log('email: ')
    log(organizer.get('email', ''))


eventJson["organizer"] = {
    "emailAddress": {
        "address":str(organizer.get('email', ''))
    }
}
```

log:

```
2019-05-17T17:05:45.421475+00:00 app[web.1]: ERROR
2019-05-17T17:05:45.421493+00:00 app[web.1]: <Response [400]>
2019-05-17T17:05:45.421501+00:00 app[web.1]: 
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Property emailAddress in payload has a value that does not match schema.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "xxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "date": "2019-05-17T17:05:45"
    }
  }
}
```

I have already checked `organizer.get('email')` content. Also, in some other events, the same structure worked well. I don't know what the schema expects.

This is the example I have found on the documentation

```
"organizer": {
    "emailAddress": {
        "name": "Megan Bowen",
        "address": "MeganB@contoso.OnMicrosoft.com"
    }
}
```

Comment: organizer.get('email') has a valid email address

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `organizer` property is automatically set the owner of the calendar where the event was created. It isn't a property you can set. If you look at the examples, you'll see that `organizer` only shows up in the Response, not the Request.

Answer (score 2):

You can't set the organizer in the POST body.

If you are using `/me/calendars/{id}/events` the user logged in is the organizer (`me`).

If you use `/users/{id | userPrincipalName}/calendars/{id}/events` you set the organizer with the `{id | userPrincipalName}` (for example with application permisions app)

Example: `/users/Guilherme@mail.com/calendars/{id}/events`. Organizer:`Guilherme@mail.com`

In the link you provided [Graph docs for Create Event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/graph/api/calendar-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=javascript#request-body) you have the **request example** (not response)